# How to get back the action bar icons after closing the search view?

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview, mobile-application, appbar

While clicking the search view icon, I am hiding the other icon from the action bar. After closing the search view, the action bar icons are replaced by a more icon. How to get back the old list of icons in the action bar?

```
class ProductListFragment : Fragment() {
.....
.......
private lateinit var sortItem:MenuItem
private lateinit var searchItem: MenuItem

override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
    searchItem=menu.findItem(R.id.category_search)
    sortItem=menu.findItem(R.id.sort)
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
}
.........
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.category_activity_menu,menu)
    val searchView=menu.findItem(R.id.category_search)?.actionView as SearchView

    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener {
        sortItem.isVisible=false
    }
    searchView.setOnCloseListener{
        true
    }


    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            searchData(newText)
            return true
        }
    })
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when(item.itemId){
        R.id.category_search->{
           
        }
        R.id.sort->{
            val bottomSheetFragment=SortBottomSheetFragment()
            bottomSheetFragment.show(parentFragmentManager,"")
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
}
```

Comment: What does R.menu.category_activity_menu look like? Also you don't seem to set it visible in onCloseListener?

Comment: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
        android:id="@+id/sort"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_sort_24"
        android:title="sort"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/category_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>

Comment: I have tried to change the isVisible state of both icon on oncCloseListener but it didn't work

Comment: If you need to add some code to clarify the question you can edit the original post which has proper formatting. Nonetheless try settings app:showAsAction to "always"

Comment: still remains the same